# Refactoring from Singleton Pattern to Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, singleton

I have code for one of my .NET Core application where I am implementing the Dependency Injections design pattern. I have two singleton calls in the `ConfigureServices` method. Those two calls are very similar; they execute where similar methods, `InitializeFirstClassClientInstanceAsync` and `InitializeSecondClassClientInstanceAsync`.

Those two methods are very similar conceptually and would like to refactor my code to combine those two methods. However, I can't find a technique that would combine the `InitializeFirstClassClientInstanceAsync` and `InitializeSecondClassClientInstanceAsync` into one method/call. Is there a way I could combine those two methods into one. Is that even possible when using such a pattern?

Thank you very much in advance

Below is my code...

The actual call for the initialization of `InitializeFirstClassClientInstanceAsync` and `InitializeSecondClassClientInstanceAsync`:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    .............
    //add classes to register query classes with DI container
    services.AddSingleton<IFirstClassQueries>(
        provider => InitializeFirstClassClientInstanceAsync(
            provider.GetService<MyClient>()).GetAwaiter().GetResult());

    services.AddSingleton<ISecondClassQueries>(
        provider => InitializeSecondClassClientInstanceAsync(
            provider.GetService<MyClient>()).GetAwaiter().GetResult());
}
```

The bodies for `InitializeFirstClassClientInstanceAsync` and `InitializeSecondClassClientInstanceAsync` are:

```cs
private static async Task<IFirstClassQueries>
    InitializeFirstClassClientInstanceAsync(DaprClient daprClient)
{
    string databaseName = "databasename";
    string containerName = "containername";
    string accountUri = "https://localhost";
    var key = GetSecret();
    DBClient client = new DBClient(accountUri, key["mykey"]);
    NotificationQueries queryService =
        new NotificationQueries(client, databaseName, containerName);
    return queryService;
}

private static async Task<ISecondClassQueries>
    InitializeSecondClassClientInstanceAsync(DaprClient daprClient)
{
    string databaseName = "databasename";
    string containerName = "containername";
    string accountUri = "https://localhost";
    var key = GetSecret();
    DBClient client = new DBClient(accountUri, key["mykey"]);            
    UserAvailabilityQueries queryService =
        new UserAvailabilityQueries(client, databaseName, containerName);
    return queryService;
}
```

Comment: Making those blocking async calls in startup is a bad idea.

Comment: Still is it possible to combine them?

Comment: I got really confused with the code. If I understood correctly, there is no good way that I am aware of "consolidating both calls" into one, because as you can check, they even return different types (IFirstClassQueries and ISecondClassQueries). And making a method return a "Tuple<IFirstClassQueries, ISecondClassQueries>" really seems... very wrong. I believe you could greatly optimise the code by using a Factory class, or by simply registering the "NotificationQueries" and "UserAvailabilityQueries" services in the DI container. Do you think one of these options would be acceptable?

Comment: @DarkCompiled I think that would be acceptable. Could you please give me more on information on how apply the Factory class/register in the DI container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution that was acceptable for us

Call for the initialization

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...................................
        //add classes to register query classes with DI container
        services.AddSingleton<CosmosClient>(provider => InitializeCosmosClientAsync(provider.GetService<DaprClient>()).GetAwaiter().GetResult());
        services.AddSingleton<IFirstClassQueries, NotificationQueries>();
        services.AddSingleton<ISecondClassQueries, UserAvailabilityQueries>();
    }
```

The body for `InitializeCosmosClientAsync`

```
    private static async Task<CosmosClient> InitializeCosmosClientAsync(DaprClient daprClient)
    {
        var accountUri = await GetAccountUri();
        var key = await GetKey();
        CosmosClient client = new CosmosClient(accountUri, key);
        return client;
    }
```